# Why InvalidCastException when awaiting Task-returning method?

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, c#-5.0

(The real title of the question should be "Why do I get a 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[System.Runtime.CompilerServices.VoidTaskResult]' to type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.INotifyCompletion'", but unfortunately this is too long for StackOverflow. :)

Hi,

I'm getting really peculiar problems when trying to `await` the execution of a method of mine. The calling code looks like this (excerpt):

```
    private async Task DownloadAddonFileAsync(dynamic addon, dynamic file, string targetFolder)
    {
        // ...
        await DownloadFileAsync(file, targetFolder, uri);
```

The DownloadFileAsync looks like this:

```
    protected async Task DownloadFileAsync(dynamic file, string targetFolder, string uri)
    {
        // ...
        var fileBytes = await AppLoaderRestClient.GetAsync<byte[]>(uri);
```

The AppLoaderRestClient.GetAsync(), in turn, looks like this:

```
    public static async Task<T> GetAsync<T>(string uri)
    {
        // ...
        if (typeof (T) == typeof (byte[]))
        {
            var result = await webClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync(uri);
            return (T) (object) result;
        }
```

So, there is actually a *chain* of Tasks here - the "inner" Task will be a Task, which will then be propagated up to the caller, and converted to a Task (i.e. a Task without a result). I presume this could be causing the issue at hand?

If I change the outermost code to this:

```
        var task = DownloadFileAsync(file, targetFolder, uri);
        task.Wait();
```

...it works flawlessly. Why?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As it sometimes turns out, I managed to find out the answer to the question while posting it here. Thought I'd share it to save someone else from headache...

The problem stems from my use of `dynamic`, or rather, the (in my opinion) slightly limited and broken way `dynamic` works in C#/.NET as of yet. If I rephrase my code like this:

```
await (Task)DownloadFileAsync(file, targetFolder, uri);
```

...it works flawlessly.

The thing here is that since one of my parameters (`file` is `dynamic`), this will be a dynamic operation. And return values seem to be somehow "messed up" from dynamic operations; the CLR is simply unable to deduce from the code above whether the method returns `Task` or `Task<T>` (or so I guess). It therefore fails trying to cast the result to an `INotifyCompletion` instance - hence, the exception.

Thanks a *lot*, Microsoft. ;)
(I think the main problem here is that the exception message was very unclear, in my opinion...)