# Exception (sometimes) is thrown when awaiting a method with dynamic argument

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, dynamic, task-parallel-library

I have the following code:

```
string commandText = await _client
       .GetCommandTextAsync("Products", x.ProductName == "Chai");
```

The second parameter (x.ProductName == "Chai") contains a dynamic clause (x.ProductName), so the resulting expression is also dynamic. When this code is executed on .NET 4.0, sometimes it throws the following exception:

> System.InvalidCastException Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[System.String]' to type
>   'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.INotifyCompletion'.

The exception is not thrown if I explicitly case the method result to Task:

```
string commandText = await (Task<string>)_client
       .GetCommandTextAsync("Products", x.ProductName == "Chai");
```

Is there a more elegant way to resolve this problem (without casting every single line of code that awaits for a dynamic result), or is this a known problem with using TPL on .NET 4.0.

I haven't experienced this on .NET 4.5.

Comment: related, possibly answering: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19157258/why-invalidcastexception-when-awaiting-task-returning-method?rq=1

Comment: I saw this post. But it doesn't explain what can be done to avoid this except for upgrading to .NET 4.5 which manages to get around this problem.

Comment: Can you try creating an GetCommandTextAsync overload that takes a second argument of type "dynamic" and calls the original method? This might be enough to help the compiler resolve the Task type statically, although I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I will try but I don't think it will work. Dynamic is viral: if a method that takes a dynamic argument, then compiler will treat its result as dynamic.

Comment: Actually, I just wrote something similar and it worked, the compiler performed normal overload resolution and correctly inferred the return type of the method. Why don't you try it and then tell me if it worked in your case?

Comment: Actually I can't change the API signature. It is exposed as non-dynamic API for the sake of the clients that don't support dynamic (Xamarin iOS). So it has to stay that way.

Comment: So you can't even create an overload? If that's the case, you can't avoid the problem at the method site, you don't want to migrate to 4.5, you don't want to cast at the call sites, what kind of solution do you expect?

Comment: I do have both 4.0 and 4.5 versions: my library is a PCL. So it's not that big deal. But I see that for devs who are still on .NET 4.0 it's quite inconvenient to manually cast method result to Task<T>. So I was wondering if there was a solution to that not related to changing API signatures.

Comment: is there await on .net 4?

Comment: @Crimson Yes if you install some updates.

Comment: Did you try compiling the code by turning off the "optimisations" ?

Comment: I didn't turn optimisation off explicitly, but AFAIK it's off by default for Debug configuration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a theory:

According to the [TaskAwaiter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.taskawaiter(v=vs.110).aspx) definition:

```
[HostProtectionAttribute(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Synchronization = true, ExternalThreading = true)]
public struct TaskAwaiter : ICriticalNotifyCompletion, INotifyCompletion
```

it seems that *TaskAwaiter* is  an **INotifyCompletion**. You said you have *dynamic* clause in your code. As MS states *dynamic* objects are mostly behaves like object. Thus casting is required in the code which is handled by run-time or compiler.

You also stated that platform is Xamarin iOS. Which possibly utilizing *HostProtectionAttribute* for example to block usage of some classes or etc.

The TaskAwaiter implementation is marked with *SecurityAction.LinkDemand* and again if we check [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.permissions.securityaction(v=vs.110).aspx) it says:

```
...
LinkDemand (do not use in the .NET Framework 4)
...
```

So conclusion is: The platform which code is running, is lacking security implementations required by Host Protection and methods are not invoked (while security is not working properly) Casting is one of "secure" operation thus this type of runtime casting fails.

if you explicitly cast like you did, there is no problem because compiler does not add the "buggy" code.

Comment: Thank you for a deep dive into the problem. The failure occurs also on a Windows machine, so it is not specific for Xamarin.iOS. Otherwise I believe you correctly described possible reasons. With an explicit cast it works fine on .NET 4, it also works fine on .NET 4.5 without a cast.