# Invalid casting exception on awaiting method call

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0, asynchronous, async-await

I am getting following exception While awaiting on method below is code.
Return type of GetData is Task>>
Also there are few await calls inside GetData function as well

Exception :

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]]]'
>   to type 'System.Runtime.CompilerServices.INotifyCompletion'.

Code Snippet :

```
try
{
   List<Dictionary<string, string>> records = await GetData(param1, param2, param3);
   return records;
}
catch (Exception e)
{
}
```

Comment: what does your `GetData` function return ??

Comment: what is the return type of `GetData`? It needs to be `Task<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>`

Comment: Return type of GetData is Task<List<Dictionary<string, string>>>

Comment: can you post your GetData function ??

Comment: Is one of your agruments dynamic? See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19157258/why-invalidcastexception-when-awaiting-task-returning-method

Comment: what are the arguments you are passing to `GetData`? Show the code for `GetData`.

Comment: There are few await calls inside GetData but will not be able to share the code inside GetData

Comment: @Ned Stoyanov : I already had look at that question , my scenario is different that waht stated in the question

Comment: Did you try `await (List<Dictionary<string, string>>)GetData(param1, param2, param3)`?

Comment: Yes tried that as well

Comment: Is the exception coming from on of the awaits inside the method or the one awaiting the method itself?

Comment: the one awaiting the method itself

Comment: post the prototype of GetData() function

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
 var task = await GetData(param1, param2, param3);
 List<Dictionary<string, string>> records = task.Result;
```